# jquery load().html - works but inner link does not (re)load

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Update... 29.8.13
The

```
$(document).on("click", ".setStamp", function ()
```

works just fine.

On testing I find that one of the actions within that click block

```
$('.setStamp').addClass('fake');
```

no longer works. This 'fake' class is a simple toggle override used...

```
if ($('.setStamp').is('.fake')) { resize-elements; $('.setStamp').removeClass('fake'); } 
else { $(this).toggleClass('large'); $container.isotope('reLayout'); }
```

If I set it using:

```
$(".arrow_in").click(function () { $('.setStamp').addClass('fake'); }
```

It is fine.
Comments?

_*_*_end Update

I am using Masonry-Isotope as a language dictionary interface where tiles are the first layer word definition. Simple eg: tile-a is the word 'test' with a synonym link 'exam'. Clicking exam loads a new definition in a corner-stamp (div float:right) = "A set of questions evaluating [link]skill[/link]".

Clicking the sub-link 'skill' uses the same class trigger as the top-level link 'exam' but... it fails to load.

Example here:http://www.buddhamind.info/br/innerLink.htm

CODE:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" class="clickable clearfix">
<div id="stamp" class="corner-stamp"><BR><center>tile<BR>
    <span style='background-color:black;color:white;cursor:pointer'>&nbsp;link&nbsp;</span>
    <BR>data<BR><BR>seen<BR>here</center></div>

<div class="element a" data-pali="Janaka-kamma" data-category="a">
    <div class="number">180</div>
    <div class="name"><button id=LINK class=setStamp>LINK</button></div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(".setStamp").click(function () { // click tile links..... MANY of these
    $("#stamp").load($('#'+$(this).attr("id")).html()+'.htm'); // load file ID.htm
        $('.setStamp').addClass('fake'); // fake class to stop 'large' resize
    $('.corner-stamp').removeClass('noStamp'); // show stamp
    $('#closeStamp').addClass('stampOn'); // stamp avoided by tiles
        $('.corner-stamp').addClass('corner_wide'); // widen stamp
        $('.corner-stamp').removeClass('corner_content');
        $('.arrow_in').addClass('arrow_vis'); // show arrow_in.png
        $('.arrow_out').removeClass('arrow_vis'); // hide arrow_out.png
        $container.isotope('reLayout'); });
</script>
```

Two questions:
Can it work?
What will make it work?

I hope all this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

To also bind jQuery events on things that are loaded in programatically (with `.load` for example), use `.on()`, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13927958/1319187) answer. So in your case:

`$(document).on("click", ".setStamp", function(){ ... });`

**Update**

If I understand correctly, the `.setStamp` from which the class `fake` is not added is loaded in with the `.load()` function. If I understand this correctly, I presume the `$('.setStamp').addClass('fake');` isn't being run on that element because the `$("#stamp").load( ... );` hasn't finished loading the content. You could however put the `.addClass()` code in the `complete`-function of the `.load()`, like so:

```
$("#stamp").load($('#'+$(this).attr("id")).html()+'.htm', function(){
   $('.setStamp').addClass('fake');
});
```

If the other code after the `.addClass('fake')` is also applied to stuff that's loaded from the `.load()` , I strongly advise you to put the `complete`-function as well. If you don't, it might load some times if the connection is very fast (like running locally), but online or if a user has a bad ping it might take much longer to load.

Comment: simply using .on in place of .bind or .click won't make it delegate the event.

Comment: How I understood his question was that the classes get loaded via `.load()`, so won't `.on()` make these links 'work' as well?

Comment: Yes, they get loaded, but `.on('click', function` is exactly identical to `.click(function`, it won't target items that don't exist yet.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13927958/1319187) answer `.on()` does do something different

Comment: Look very closely at the syntax in that answer vs the syntax in your answer. They are very different and perform two different tasks.

Comment: .on() = Attach an event handler function for one <B>or more</B> events... thx guys

Comment: I tried adding a new 'block' - answer my own question.. so,On testing I find that one of the actions

    $('.setStamp').addClass('fake');

no longer works. This class is a simple toggle override for

 $container.delegate( '.element', 'click', function(){ // change size of clicked element 
 if ($('.setStamp').is('.fake')) { $('.setStamp').removeClass('fake'); }
 else { $(this).toggleClass('large');
   $container.isotope('reLayout'); } // zx; if-else stops resize on click-setting stamp text
   });

Any comments?

Comment: @Arfa: please update your question with the necessary code, write **Update** before it or so to make it clear it is an additional error.

Comment: I updated my answer again @Arfa, hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: @arbitter - no, as per my orig ex. the fake class is added with all the other class adjusts. Just that when I use the $(document).on("click", ".setStamp", function(){...} it doesn't work. I have reset an instance of the original $(".setStamp").click(function () {...} just for the fake class. That works OK but I don't see why. There is only the one load() call using a single ID but I appreciate your suggestion as, yes, I develop local. I very much appreciate your time but unless you see a problem resetting the orig. just for fake class I am happy. Still, if you have an easy explaination then OK